# VS code auto compete not working properly when creating a mongoose schema

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, mongoose-schema

Any idea why the intellisense is completely useless when I create a mongoose schema? Even tho it used to work in the past.

[image]

I have searched a lot about this topic but unfortunately couldn't find anything that can help.

Node.js related extensions I have: `EsLint` `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` [Node extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=swellaby.node-pack) `npm intellesense` `path intellesense` `REST Client` `Visual studio Intellicode`

Comment: @Hamid it's funny how this was 1 year and a half ago and it still no clue how to solve it

Comment: I also faced same problem for mongoose in VSCode. I was searching the solution in Google nearly one hour and not found the answer. I also installed mongoose globally as @Omar H. Mohamed suggested. It also didn't work for me. Dose any one know the solution? Please solve the problem if you know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but I found that if I am nesting inside a property it works.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

I am still searching for what is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need to install mongoose globally on your device
So Run This Command

```
npm install mongoose -g
```